# Javascript disallow space only in input area

Tags: javascript

I tried using following method to ban users from leaving only space in the input area with no luck:

method one:

```
var formSub  = $('#formsub').val();

if (formSub == null || formSub == "") {
  return false;
}
```

method two:

```
if (formSub.trim() == "" || formSub.trim() == " ") {
  return false;
}
```

method three:

```
if ($.trim(formSub) == "" || $.trim(formSub) == " ") {
  return false;
}
```

Any thought? :)

Comment: Is it a typo that you are using `form` and `formSub`?

Comment: @k0pernikus thanks for catching the typo. I didn't copy and paste. :)

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since that question is about detecting an empty string, not one just containing white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple regexp:

```
/\S/.test(formSub)
```

where `\S` refers to any non-white space character.

This removes the dependency on `trim` (not found in IE<=8) and/or jQuery.

Comment: you are obviously a master of regex! Do you happen to know how to allow only numbers 0-9 and signs inlcuding .+- (yes tel validation). I've found some example but they all limit the length, I don't want to limit the length since most users are international.

Comment: Someone asked a question here actually, and no valid answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677058/regex-optionally-allowed-parentheses-dots-dashes-spaces-and-plus-sign-in-pho

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. It's `[0-9\-\(\)\+\.\s]`, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker That will make sure at least one of the characters is present, but will pass through others. You want `/[^-+0-9()/`, which will return true if any invalid characters are present. This is called a "negated character class" (see the leading `^` character).

Comment: `/[^-+.0-9()]/` you mean? It will console log invalid regex with your expression. Also, I've noticed I also need space in the expression. I tried `/[^-+.0-9()\S]/` and it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Ops, it should be `/[^-+.0-9()\s]/` my bad (with a small s).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `formSub == null || formSub.trim() === ""`.

`===` and `==` isn't exactly the same. `== ""` can means `true`, and any string is "true".

Comment: An input element will never have a value of null, and hence you do not need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (formValue.length === 0 || !formValue.trim()) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It would seem that the left and right side of the condition mean the same thing. If `formValue.length` is 0, then `formValue.trim()` will be falsy anyway.

Comment: @torazaburo If `formValue.length` is 0, `formValue.trim()` will not be invoked due to [short-circuit evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

Haha! This is a good one you actually walk around the solution all along.

So here for example, you actually already trimmed all the spaces by using .trim()

```
if (formSub.trim() == "" || formSub.trim() == " ") {
  return false;
}
```

Correct would be just,

```
if (formSub == " ") {
  return false;
}
```

This will be the most useful, it passes if someone actually wrote something different from spaces, or other invisible characters ;)
Google "Javascript Regex for more info"

```
if (/\S/.test(formSub)) {
   // String is not empty
}
else{
  // String is empty and not usefull
}
```

Cheers ;) ! +1 Appreciated

Comment: What is the user entered two spaces?

Comment: I know all right, but the question was specific to only space. So here is the solution. -- UPDATED